# How do I get serializer field value inside serializer

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have this ModelSerializer:

```
class BidSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Bid
        fields = '__all__'

    def validate_amount(self, value):
        auction = Auction.objects.get(id=self.validated_data['auction'])
        if auction.price_step % value:
            raise serializers.ValidationError()
```

But it throws throws "is_valid() should be called" exception. How do I properly access auction field value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want to check one field based on value of the other  you just should use [object-level-validation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#object-level-validation)

```
class BidSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Bid
        fields = '__all__'

    def validate(self, data):
        auction = Auction.objects.get(id=data['auction'])
        amount = data.get('amount')
        if auction.price_step % amount:
            msg = {'amount' : ['this field is not valid']}
            raise serializers.ValidationError(msg)
```